# How Do I Save an Integer After a Restart SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Simple as that, how do I save an Integer for score after the user has restarted the app.  I'm trying to use SpriteKit for everything, so keep that in mind.  I've tried NSUserDefaults but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Well it does work so _show_ what you are doing.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is what you should use. Please check your code or post the code that seems to not be working for you.

Comment: You can't "use SpriteKit for everything" because the SpriteKit framework doesn't contain any I/O.

NSUserDefaults is the simplest way to go here, and should work. Tell how why and how it doesn't and we can help you.

Comment: Googling "ios save data" yields a link like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197448/how-to-save-data-in-ios

Comment: If you are having trouble with NSUserDefaults, then showing your code and any errors would be helpful. But I encourage you to first check out the many questions on this site that already cover this topic.

Answer (score 1):

As msgambel points out below, you can save integers directly into NSUserDefaults via something like:

[`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"one"];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger%3aforKey%3a)

And separately, if you put an integer into a "`NSNumber`" object (i.e. an Objective C object), you can save these in NSUserDefaults or include these objects in arrays or dictionaries.

Check out [`[NSNumber numberWithInteger:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithInteger%3a)

Comment: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"one"];` works just fine.

Comment: you're right!  I'll include that in my answer above...